# Can't upgrade docker on rackspace

Tags: docker, rackspace

I have a rackspace docker-machine set up and I need to upgrade it from 1.9 to 1.10. Using the docker-machine upgrade command says that it upgrades the machine, but docker-machine ls remains showing 1.9. If I spin up a new rackspace docker-machine it correctly shows at 1.10.

Does anyone know how to correctly upgrade a rackspace driven docker-machine?

Here is my current docker toolset version information:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd
$ docker-machine -v
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87
$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.6.2, build 4d72027
```

Comment: not sure how docker-machine works other then on my laptop but did you try restarting docker and seeing what a `docker version` says?

Comment: Tried a full computer restart.  I even created a new rackspace instance that came up at 1.10

Comment: did you tried upgrade it via your package manager? are there any errors ? what distribution of OS do you run ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by update it via the package manager.  I am attempting to manage this server from an OSX 10.11.4 machine, but the actual server is running whatever Rackspace uses

Answer (score 0):

The commands you are running are showing you the version of the software installed on your machine, the latest version of `docker-machine` is `docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87`

To ensure that the docker service is up to date run the following `docker-machine ssh` then run one of the following (I believe the dpkg command) `rpm -qa | grep docker` OR `dpkg -l | grep docker`, this will tell you what the installed version of Docker is on the server.

Comment: `root@XXt:~# dpkg -l | grep docker
rc  docker-engine                       1.9.1-0~trusty                amd64        Docker: the open-source application container engine
ii  lxc-docker-1.9.1                    1.9.1                         amd64        Linux container runtime`

Comment: what happens if you try to do a `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` ?

Comment: After both updates dpkg results haven't changed

Comment: OK, lets try `apt-get install docker` ?

Comment: Now I get this: `root@XX:~# dpkg -l | grep docker
ii  docker                              1.5-1                            amd64        System tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications
rc  docker-engine                       1.9.1-0~trusty                   amd64        Docker: the open-source application container engine
rc  lxc-docker-1.9.1                    1.9.1                            amd64        Linux container runtime`